# how to post values from content page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

in my web application I have master page and it has too many content pages and in my content pages I want to post form to other URL. but its not posting the values to other page in this way.

But When I do the same code in simple aspx page without masterpage it works well.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<form id="frmPay">
    <div>

    <!-- Receiver Details -->
    <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" id="merchant_id" value="xxgxg" >
    <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" id="merchant_key" value="gxgagag" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" id="return_url" value="http://www.widget.co.za/payment_finished" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" id="cancel_url" value="http://www.widget.co.za/payment_cancelled" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="http://www.widget.co.za/payment_notify" runat="server">

    <!-- Payer Details -->
    <input type="hidden" name="name_first" id="name_first"  value="Bob" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="name_last" id="name_last" value="Smith" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="email_address" id="email_address" value="bob.smith@example.com" runat="server">

    <!-- Transaction Details -->
    <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" id="m_payment_id" value="TRN123456789" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="200.00" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="Widget Model 123" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description" id="item_description" value="Widget Model 123" runat="server">

    <!-- Transaction Options -->
    <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" id="email_confirmation" value="" runat="server">

    <!-- Security -->
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signature" value="" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Dai. Its Done. Question is rephrased. Please Now See..

Comment: How do you know it's not posting the values? What's the code on your server? You are using the html and not the asp.net controls.

Comment: @Remy: On other side when it goes it says you page is missing the required parameters. Even they are in my html inside the form tag. And so what If I am using simple basic html controls but I made them server side by runat="server".

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` element does not have an `action=""` attribute - the form won't go anywhere (or rather, it will submit to the current URI (whatever it is)). If you want to submit values to another page in ASP.NET you can read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14092/Cross-Page-Posting-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Comment: I know when I am clicking the button and it has postback URL sending the page there.